# Is it possible to build .app file without the source code? If we just have the app installed on the iOS device and can extract .ipa

Tags: ios, appium

If we have an iOS app, it is a test build (enterprise build) deployed on Test Flight.

I can extract the .ipa after installing the app on the device and connecting it to iTunes.

And then I zip the .ipa file and unzip it, it shows .app file within the extracted folder of that app.

Can I use this .app file to run iOS appium scripts on simulator?

I tried doing it but it gave error -

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:387:31)
at null. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:308:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (childprocess.js:820:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 115895.509 ms - 182

Can someone please suggest some steps to launch this enterprise iOS test app on iOS simulator using appium ?

Comment: Device app are built for ARM processors. Simulator apps are built for Intel processors. Two completely different and incompatible processors.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The device app is compiled for arm.  The simulator runs intel code.